# Can't upgrade GNUPG?

Tags: gnupg

I'm trying to upgrade my 1.4.14 GNUPG to 2.0.26 version and the repository has 1.4.14 version... I tryied removing it and building the lastest version from the official GNUPG website downloading its source code (2.0.26), but I can't do it! it is always 1.4.14! and gpg generates this key:

-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
**Version: GnuPG v1**

It generates v1 keys, that's bad... I wan't the lastest version to generate my keys, is more safe, doesn't it?

How can I repair it?

Thanks in advance!

(I'm using Linux Mint, but this happened in Ubuntu too)

Comment: If you're currently doing this on Mint, it would be better if you asked this on [unix.se].

Answer (score 9):

### GnuPG 1 and 2

First of all, GnuPG 1.4.14 is not really outdated, there are two branches of GnuPG developed at the same time. Also see [Are gnupg and gnupg2 compatible with each other?](https://superuser.com/questions/655246/are-gnupg-and-gnupg2-compatible-with-each-other)

On Debian and derivated distributions, GnuPG 1 is installed as `gpg`, whereas GnuPG 2 is installed as `gpg2` (but you might need to install the `gnupg2` package).

### Key Versions

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1
```

This is *not* an OpenPGP v1 key, the comment just indicates that GnuPG 1 created it. Both GnuPG 1 and 2 generate OpenPGP v4 keys. You can see what format is actually used by running (no matter whether using `gpg` or `gpg2`)

```
gpg --export [key-id] | gpg --list-packets | head
```

which will output something like

```
:public key packet:
    version 4, algo 1, created 1356475387, expires 0
```

### (Not) Building GnuPG on Your own

I strongly recommend *not* building GnuPG on your own. Apart from verifying sources, you need to regularly recompile to get security updates. [Mint Linux already includes a fairly recent version of GnuPG 2 (2.0.22)](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/gnupg2) with all security fixes backported, it should be totally fine sticking with that until a newer distribution will bring a new minor version.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this would help but if you use linux mint you can download it here http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/gnupg2 or if you use ubuntu you can download it here https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnupg2/

Answer (score 0):

**[Older versions of gnupg are insecure.](https://gnupg.org/)**

> GnuPG 1.4.23 released (2018-06-11)   **important**
>
> Although GnuPG 1.4 is of very limited use today we did a maintenance
>   release to address the critical security bug CVE-2017-7526. See the
>   download section on how to get this version.
>
> GnuPG 2.2.8 released> (2018-06-08)    **important**
>
> This version fixes a critical security bug. Either this version or a
>   vendor provided fix should be installed. There are also a few other
>   changes; see the announcement mail. This is CVE-2018-12020 and our bug #4012.

To update to a safe version, you might have to install a backport [explained further here](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/).